# Can anyone identify this drupe fruit & seed?

Tags: identification

This fruit & seed was given to me to identify -no leaves etc. Fruit is 4cm (1 inch) long, 3cm wide. Ribbed seed 3cm long with 1 seed per fruit. Drupe fruit flesh is brownish inside & faintly apple scented -it's mid August (late winter in New Zealand) so probably bletted. Phyllis [image]

Comment: It looks like an Elaeagnus fruit, but I'm not certain which one. Do you have any more info on or pictures of the shrub it came from?

Comment: No sorry-  an acquaintance walked out in town streets at lunchtime, came back with this fruit and seed and asked another friend what it was - she gave it to me! The flesh is quite soft inside.

Comment: Thanks Michelle - I just looked online for Eleagnus varieties and think it is probably Elaeagnus x ebbingei. The colour of mine is darker and browner than described but, as I said, I think it is over-ripe and bletted. The unusual ribbed stone certainly looks like this Eleagnus.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a jujube.
I had a difficult time identifying this fruit for my parents as well. The fruit starts to grow as a green color. As it ripped it turns brown although at a distance the drupe looks red.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Nancy for your comment. I've looked online and feel that though there are similarities with my fruit, the blotches are much larger than the regular darker spots on my fruit and the stem ends are different. I still tend to think mine is an Eleagnus.